# Using layout with content_for/yield when rendering collection partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, view, partial, content-for

I'm trying to reuse a card layout throughout my app for various collections. I was hoping I could do this with content_for and yield, as described in the [rendering guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield), and my exact use case is described [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#collection-partial-layouts). But I'm not able to get the content from the partial inserted into the layout. Here's the setup for rendering a collection of 'entities':

The view (index.html.erb):

```
<%= render partial: 'entity', collection: @entities, layout: 'card' %>
```

The partial (_entity.html.erb):

```
<% content_for(:left_icon) do %>
  <i class="fas fa-city fa-2x"></i>
<% end %>
```

The card layout (_card.html.erb) uses yield to retrieve content specific to the collection (like a certain left-icon as in this snippet)

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body d-flex">
    <%= yield :left_icon %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But only an empty line is rendered where the icon should be:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body d-flex">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to be able to render the card with content?

Comment: If you use `<%= content_for :left_icon %>` it'll work. Why? I'd like to know

Comment: Thanks for the reply - but it's not working. `content_for` doesn't need the equal-sign in `<%=`.

Comment: I meant replacing `yield` for `content_for`, no?